# Category information or relationship are not getting updated

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-server, commerce-catalog

I am using using Commerce Server 11.0 in Sitecore 8.1 update 1.
I have some categories which are shown across Menu in my websites.
The categories are getting updated in the commerce server catalog from an API by an Incremental job. Whenever the structure or sorting of the Categories are modified I do not see it showing up in the Menu even tough the updated category relationship are visible in the commerce server catalog.

[image]

What I am missing here? Have anyone faced or fixed such kind of issue?

Comment: How do you access these categories from your website? If you use commerce connect, have a look how the categories are sorted in Content Editor, if the order is updated there correctly.

Comment: We do not use commerce connect. The categories from the API is added to the Sitecore commerce Server with an incremental job scheduled in Sitecore. I do not see any categories in Content Editor as shown in the Commerce Server Catalog Manager (screenshot in the Question). Please help me with the details.